# How to read attributes in controller class

Tags: symfony, attributes

Hello i have some anotation classes to transform to atributes.

one of my anotation/attribute class:

```
namespace App\Annotations;

use Attribute;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ControllerEvent;

/**
 * @Annotation
 * @NamedArgumentConstructor
 * @Target({"CLASS", "METHOD"})
 */
#[Attribute(Attribute::IS_REPEATABLE | Attribute::TARGET_CLASS | Attribute::TARGET_METHOD)]
class Authenticaded extends _Annotation
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function execute(
        ContainerInterface $container,
        ControllerEvent $event
    ) {
        // logick
    }
}
```

how to read that class when defined as attribute?

my methods to read anotations from EventSubscriberInterface:

```
private function handleClassAnnotation(
    ControllerEvent $event,
    \ReflectionClass $controller
) {
    foreach (
        [Authenticaded::class]
        as $class
    ) {
        $annotation = $this->reader->getClassAnnotation(
            $controller,
            $class
        );

        if ($annotation instanceof $class) {
            $continue = $annotation->execute(
                $this->container,
                $event
            );
            if (!$continue) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

What is necesary to change to read attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Tnx Chafik Kerboute, based on your answer I managed to do next code:

```
private function attributeToInstances(array $attributes): array
{
    $instances = [];

    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        $attributeName = $attribute->getName();
        $instance = $attribute->newInstance();
        $instances[$attributeName] = $instance;
    }

    return $instances;
}

private function handleClassAnnotation(
    ControllerEvent $event,
    \ReflectionClass $controller
) {
    $attributes = $this->attributeToInstances($controller->getAttributes());

    foreach (
        [Authenticaded::class]
        as $class
    ) {
        $temp = $attributes[$class]
            ?? $this->reader->getClassAnnotation(
                $controller,
                $class
            );

        if ($temp instanceof $class) {
            $continue = $temp->execute(
                $this->container,
                $event
            );
            if (!$continue) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```